# Do we need to close the System.Net.WebRequest's ResponseStream?

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream, response, system.net

I was wondering will I end up having any unclosed streams from this code:

```
   Public Function [Get](ByVal url As String) As String
        Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse.GetResponseStream)
            Return reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Function
```

What about this:

```
  Public Function Get2(ByVal url As String) As String
        Using stream = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
                Return reader.ReadToEnd
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Basically, do we need to close the `System.Net.WebRequest`'s `ResponseStream` ?

Comment: No you don't need to close it, using is a wrapper for try{ Stream stream; ... }catch {..} finally { if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); } }

Comment: @Artur: I think you've misunderstood the question - it's not about whether you need to explicitly call Close, it's whether closing the StreamReader (via a using statement) is enough to close the stream and the WebResponse.

Comment: @Artur: `using` finally calls `Dispose()` on the object, not `Close()`. Disposing an object should close open resources, but `using` doesn't do so directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *either* need to close the response stream *or* you need to close the response. Note that closing a `StreamReader` wrapping a `Stream` will close the stream anyway, so the first version should be okay. (Note that I'm deeming "dispose with a Using statement" to be semantically equal to "close in a finally block" - there's no benefit in explicitly calling `Close` instead of just disposing of the stream or response.)

I *believe* that closing the stream is good enough - that you don't need to close the response as well - and indeed [that's what MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx), but personally I'd do so for clarity:

```
Public Function [Get](ByVal url As String) As String
    Using response = WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse
        Using reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
            Return reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

(There's a *theoretical* benefit here that it will close the response if `GetResponse` returns successfully but either `GetResponseStream` or the `StreamReader` constructor throws an exception. I don't expect that to have any *practical* implications.)

If you don't close *anything*, you could very easily run into timeouts in future requests to the same host - the "open" response will essentially hog the connection to that host, and by default there's a limit of two open connections per host. This is a very common cause of timeouts - there are lots of SO questions where folks are getting timeouts due to not closing anything.

Comment: @Artur: Which bit? I'm very well aware of what a Using statement means in IL - which bit of my answer goes against that?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to call the Close method on the WebResponse, but doing so is not harmful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: Doing this will show up the bad knowledge of C# language specification, ECMA standart. Again, using statement is a syntax shugar wrapper for try { Stream stream; ... } catch {..} finally { if (stream != null) { stream.Close(); } } block.

Comment: I agree you but I was just reporting what MSDN says about that